# Where has the xen.git git repository for Xen gone since the Kernel.org attack?

Tags: xen, git, xenserver

Has it been put up anywhere else for now?  I know the Kernel has been put up on Github for now.

The git url that we were using was, git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/jeremy/xen.git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/jsgf/linux-xen

See also:
http://xen.markmail.org/search/?q=kernel.org#query:kernel.org%20date%3A201109%20+page:1+mid:yx3unzyyl5pxqiya+state:results

Answer (score 2):

Not sure were it went, but you could use a recent (>3.0) kernel which includes all functionality that's needed to run the kernel as dom0.